# Angular 5 separate body classes

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a login screen and a dashboard screen. The body classes for those screens are different like:

```html
<body class="hold-transition skin-black-light sidebar-mini" > // for dashboard
<body class="hold-transition login-page"> // for login
```

The entry point of my angular 5 project is index.html. How can I separate the body, based on the above mentioned pages?

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <base href="/">

<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-black-light sidebar-mini" >
    <app-root>Loading.....</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of 2 body tags, you can create a directive which adds class based on the login screen or dashboard screen.

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani - Where I need to write the directive? How and Where can I access the same? It would be good if you explain this as your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of **`Renderer2`** in `Angular`.

You can **add a class to body** using 
**`this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'dashboard');`** in your required `component`.

**Dashboard:** (I added **Dashboard** class)

```
    import { Renderer2, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';


        export class dashboardComponent implements OnDestroy {

          constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
            this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'dashboard');
           }

          ngOnDestroy() {
            this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'dashboard');
          } 
    }
```

**Login:** (I added **Login** class)

```
import { Renderer2, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';


export class loginComponent implements OnDestroy {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'login');
   }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'login');
  } 
}
```

[**Here is a Working DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-tqx1ho?file=app%2Fviews%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that in `index.html`, it's a bad practice.

Do it in `app.component` instead, with something like:

```
<app-root
  [ngClass]="{
    'skin-black-light': isOnLoginPage()
    'sidebar-mini': isOnLoginPage()
    'login-page': !isOnLoginPage()
  }"
>
```

Where `isOnLoginPage` is a function defined in `ts` file which somehow determines (for example - by url) if user is on login page or not.